# activating custom class button dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using javascript to dynamically create a button where I set all the attributes and show it on my page. Then using jQuery I implement hover and click logic to change the layout of the button's class. When the button is created it's class layout is what it should be, but when hovered over or clicked it does not change like it does when I create it before runtime.

The javascipt code:

```
function createbutton()
{
var btn = document.createElement("input");
btn.setAttribute("type", "button");
btn.setAttribute("class", "fg-button ui-state-default ui-corner-all");
btn.setAttribute("value", "click!");
btn.setAttribute("onclick", "createbutton()");

theParent = document.getElementById("content");
theParent.appendChild(btn);
}
$(function(){
    //all hover and click logic for buttons     
    $(".fg-button:not(.ui-state-disabled)")
    .hover(
        function(){ 
            $(this).addClass("ui-state-hover"); 
        },
        function(){ 
            $(this).removeClass("ui-state-hover"); 
        }
    )
    .mousedown(function(){
            $(this).parents('.fg-buttonset-single:first').find(".fg-button.ui-state-active").removeClass("ui-state-active");
            if( $(this).is('.ui-state-active.fg-button-toggleable, .fg-buttonset-multi .ui-state-active') ){ $(this).removeClass("ui-state-active"); }
            else { $(this).addClass("ui-state-active"); }   
    })
    .mouseup(function(){
        if(! $(this).is('.fg-button-toggleable, .fg-buttonset-single .fg-button,  .fg-buttonset-multi .fg-button') ){
            $(this).removeClass("ui-state-active");
        }
    });
});
```

In HTML:

```
<input type="button" onclick="createbutton()" value="CLICK" >
<div id="content">
</div>
```

Is there another attribute I should set, or should I do something else to activate the jQuery function when the button is created?

Edit(updated function):

```
$('body').on(
{
    mousedown: function() 
    {
        $(this).parents('.fg-buttonset-single:first').find(".fg-button.ui-state-active").removeClass("ui-state-active");
        if( $(this).is('.ui-state-active.fg-button-toggleable, .fg-buttonset-multi .ui-state-active') ){ $(this).removeClass("ui-state-active"); }
        else { $(this).addClass("ui-state-active"); }

    },
    mouseup: function() 
    {
        if(! $(this).is('.fg-button-toggleable, .fg-buttonset-single .fg-button,  .fg-buttonset-multi .fg-button') ){$(this).removeClass("ui-state-active");}
    },
    mouseenter: function()
    {
        $(this).addClass("ui-state-hover"); 
    },
    mouseleave: function()
    {
        $(this).removeClass("ui-state-hover"); 
    }       
}, '.fg-button:not(.ui-state-disabled)');
```

Comment: You should run your JS through JSLint, and consider the suggestions you get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to set up event delegation so that dynamically generated elements are recognised by the event handler. The basic principle is that you set the event handler on a static element (one that exists when the page is loaded, and will always exist) that will contain all of the elements you want to trigger the callback function - if there isn't a suitable container element defined in your HTML, you can use the `body`, though the more specific you can be the better.

If you're using jQuery 1.7+, you'll want the [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function. Since you're binding multiple events, you'd be best off using the event map syntax:

```
$('body').on({
    mousedown: function() {

    },
    mouseup: function() {

    },
    ...
}, '.fg-button:not(.ui-state-disabled)');
```

Note that `hover` isn't an actual event, the function is just a shorthand for binding to two different events (`mouseenter` and `mouseleave`).

If you're using a version prior to jQuery 1.7, take a look at the [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) function instead.

Comment: Yes I'm using jQuery 1.7 and used your advice to change the jQuery function. The same problem still exists though, I'll edit my question with the updated function.

Comment: @Glenn Could you create a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @Glenn Is the HTML in the jsFiddle the same as what's on your actual page? The jQuery code is looking for parent elements that aren't present there, which seems like it would cause problems.

Comment: Hmm, you're right! I updated it with the previous working function and edited the html to show what I'm trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/6h7fm/2/ I don't really see how I should implement the standard jQuery function into the .on() function

Comment: @Glenn This (minorly updated) [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anthonygrist/6h7fm/3/) seems to work. I inspected the button elements with Firebug, and the classes are added or removed in response to the correct events. Not really sure what you're expecting to happen that isn't, but the code to bind the event handlers is correct.

Comment: Nice this works exactly like it should, I see what I did wrong now.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

U can use a delegate method:
$('#container').on('click', 'button', createbutton);

Answer (score 0):

You should not rely on event listeners like `.hover()` or `.mousedown()`. **They only attach listeners to elements that already exist on runtime**. On runtime yout button does not yet exist, until function `createbutton()` is called later on. You should either use the soon-to-be deprecated `.live().` or get used to the all-in-one `.on()` and `.off()` methods.

Comment: "soon-to-be deprecated"? jQuery 1.7 has been around for a while now, it's very much already deprecated.